# Installation of Ubuntu 12.10 not sucessful in Samsung np100 notebook

Tags: installation, boot, 12.10, kernel, live-usb

After installation of Ubuntu 12.10 from USB made using the *Startup Disk Creator*, on new **Samsung NP-N100S-E01IN** notebook it does not boot.

On booting the system just runs an update and stops with message

```
Stopping   Kernel...
```

Even recovery mode is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing from your USB flash Drive during the install did you change where Grub installation on the usb or the hard drive. second are you installing 64 bit or 32 bit. Third If possible download the ISO from ubuntu web site i looked up the model Samsung NP-N100S-E01IN  comes with Dos and meego I would try booting from the usb drive it could be possible that the grub boot loader was installed  on the usb drive if that doesn't work try installing again with out the updates and in the install menu select something different find the drive on the notebook reformat to ext4 check box for boot \ and make sure you change where the Grub boot loader install to the hard drive